# Removing duplicates for a column including rows adjacent and append duplicates to the above

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am wanting to `delete duplicates for Column D` and `delete rows adjacent` to it where the duplicate existed. I am wanting to remove gaps and so to append to the above. I have represented this below in a Table. The data is constantly changing in row size.  We have used VBA traditionally but we are now using Python and have to change this part of the job.

What data does: https://ibb.co/gwh0Hb

Expectant/What I am trying to achieve: https://ibb.co/f08Dnb

The following tends to remove duplicates and place it in one column, however the rows beside duplicates beside it are not deleted and the columns are not appended.

Below code -

```
import openpyxl
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Documents/dwa.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active # keep naming convention consistent
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Documents/123.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active # keep naming convention consistent
values = []
col_e = 6 # easier to remember
values = set() # no duplicates by default; faster 'in' searching
for row in ws1.iter_rows(row_offset=1): # if you have a header
    if row[col_e].value not in values:
        values.add(row[col_e].value)
    else:
        row[col_e].value = '', 
wb2.save('C:/Users/Documents/123.xlsx')
```

I have attempted to add -

`values.add(row[col_c].value)` a well as other column values however I am yet to have any success with this.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a solution using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('remove_duplicates.xlsx')
# Identifying duplicates only by column 'C4'
# Further details https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html
df.drop_duplicates(['C4'],keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Input excel is like this:

[image]

And the output will be like this:
[image]